# How can I get a VAT refund after I've left the UK from Luton Airport?

Tags: uk, tax-refunds, ltn

I'm a non-EU citizen. I left London from Luton Airport at 23:30. I did not find the blue HM customs post, so I took the VAT refund paper with me. How I can request the refund? Can I send it by post? To which address?

Comment: Related question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5496/vat-refund-at-luton-airport. This is not a duplicate because it deals with what happens after you've already left.

Answer (score 5):

Your citizenship is not relevant; where you live is. You need to leave the EU at the latest three months after you bought the goods. I think you may already be too late unless you are still in the EU and are planning to leave it shortly.

To quote from [the HM Revenue & Customs website](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/vat/sectors/consumers/overseas-visitors.htm):

> If you're travelling outside the EU, you must show your goods,
>   receipts and your refund form to UK customs staff at the airport
>   you're leaving from. Make sure you arrive at the airport early so that
>   you have plenty of time to deal with the customs staff before your
>   departure.
>
> If you're travelling to another country within the EU before you
>   finally leave the EU, then you must show your goods and refund form to
>   customs officials in that country when you leave it.
>
> ...
>
> If there aren't any customs officials at the port or airport you're
>   leaving from, there will be a telephone you can use to ring an
>   official or a clearly marked customs post box in which you can leave
>   your refund form. Customs officials will collect it from there and if
>   they are satisfied that all requirements have been met, they will
>   contact the retailer to arrange your VAT refund.

There does not appear to be any provision for posting the form.